# Retrieving key, value of json data python

Tags: python, json

I have a Json file with a dictionary that looks like

```
{"tvs": 92, "sofas": 31, "chairs": 27, "cpus": 007}
```

I'm trying loop though the dictionary and print the key with its corresponding value, in my code I'm getting a too many values to unpack error.

```
with open('myfile.json', "r") as myfile:
json_data = json.load(myfile)
for e, v in json_data:
  for key, value in e.iteritem():
    print key, value
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, by default a `dict` will iterate over its keys.

```
for key in json_data:
    print key
# tvs, sofas, etc...
```

Instead, it seems like you want to iterate over the key-value pairs. This can be done by calling `.items()` on the dictionary.

```
 for key, value in json_data.items():
    print key, value
```

Or you can iterate over just the values by calling `.values()`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
with open('myfile.json', "r") as myfile:
    json_data = json.load(myfile)
    for e, v in json_data.items():
        print e,v
```

You have an extra loop in your code, also, the input file has invalid data `007`. Loading it into json should give you an error.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
>>> json = {"tvs": 92, "sofas": 31, "chairs": 27, "cpus": 007}
>>> for j in json:
...     print j, json[j]
... 
chairs 27
sofas 31
cpus 7
tvs 92
```